# how do i get the rupee symbol on the Y axis of the vega charts, i m getting the doller($) symbol through format but not getting rupee symbol

Tags: javascript, vega

```
how do i get the rupee symbol on the Y axis of the vega charts, i m getting the doller($) symbol through format but not getting rupee symbol
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "x",
      "labelAngle": -90,
      "labelPadding": 29,
      "format": "Q%q %Y",
      "ticks": true,
      "tickCount": "month",
      "labelFontSize": 11
    },
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y", "tickCount": 5,"format": "$,f"}
  ],
```

```
"format": "$,f"
```

how do i get the rupee symbol on the Y axis of the vega charts, i m getting the doller($) symbol through format but not getting rupee symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom label strings for Vega axis labels, see: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/axes/

The Indian Rupee Sign is represented by the Unicode Character U+20B9, or "\\u20B9" within Vega spec.

Here is an example of the Vega bar chart with Rupee symbol on Y-axis labels.

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETJBBpRdSRdtgnM2uAA8kCHABs4U7QHc6MbcSQOGcbQ5ITHAOENoQMGyu4toMOBLaCGwMEP6RpIqU0iDusvRoACwADEUy8DRkWGgATCUyOEiysjTiZDWlckiYKKgA2qDidnBoIN1MTtnevgpo-SBQXeRsigCeI5rZdsnimDUAHAC+UqALmEurIwBCm0kMO2gCAkcni2TLa+gAwjfbu6gFAGZnvNXu8RgARH53P4ATgAjMDTucPiAAKJQ+6oPYI44gs5vC7oABiGL+AiBuKRBJRAHFSWg4TDEaDCSAABL0rEAdgOAF0+TIDGRBqFZgMhiNMGw2A41DhJj4-GhgEcQBIxSA4KQdhARoo4FBMKhbqk2BlsnFZIsRlbMAwECBgVq4Dq9QajSa4MldjJLdb0CrHfzeYKFk5dX1xQhhuhrNAfMMZJgVjgYyA9OJZNlZGxkC1lZ1upKghMZAAzGghLPoKlg1WKJCtNO5fL1RrNVpoIqUIoCGSKbbVzCKPzAwbRkYreOluS5pD51CgW09UYlxMgCtVkZbaGOmTiQwx4d+fuNshp8qVXYCkBIawzSNq5Quv7ptjYXPZadpuNh4bA5ZK0xEAnDLH0QG-SdIJkF0oDYeQC0CYJRUXEA-TOAszmsP5QCFEURgAcgAHSIhhakuGFtAI7QAGptDLZZkEwAAKW17UoKYTyoyhqjLAiAEo9w3GgHAcAtOLTCAzhCcYlVVM8JlQiSu1VBidgAZRoAAvGNQGU1A4WqeSHAqDQ9MVNNlCvIS9FSEzxF0kB9JABAaCaCZVVkaxxIstAAFongOIKb2QRQAGsIzmZNUzdQ1sjLAcHVQ5di3Gf8YPEOCENQl84EUAtvNQyDY2g4StxrFk1lVFsYALYqQF-BNsgzascRAD5cL-KCuvLSsHGrW9bnuVUVmqOquvQKceqc3zUCKILfRwW1HIrUSfOmEYpLgGSNoWjAzTygtVrEpTZpAfUs2C4ForTLDwNg+DHNy-LUJ8Uz1qVGtnps-QQhaRznKYd8pQdVSRJO8yNvQABiAE4cdVV0McwrOqakrprwnxJWlWUVEoWsLhkFqu0oJ4ZA6iCJva0rMZO0YcblSgd3uGQ2DLMtUj+PyjKTGwcIg0ysfQKUZUZ5nr160SAHkGigOgPiihRXzYhBtAAXg17QRdx+UZH0+bcX0hF+SC-kgA)

[image]

```
"axes": [
    { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale" },

    { "orient": "left", 
      "scale": "yscale",
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {
            "text": {"signal": "'\\u20B9 ' + format(datum.value, '.2f')"},
            "fill": {"value": "steelblue"},
            "angle": {"value": 0},
            "fontSize": {"value": 12},
            "align": {"value": "right"},
            "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
            "dx": {"value": -5}
          }
        }
      }
    }

  ],
```

Comment: how can i brings (commas) in number in thousand and lakh format .Ex 1,23,455.00

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a locale configuration to the locale object. You can read how here: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/locale/

Answer (score 0):

One way to format numbers in [lakh format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) including the Rupee symbol is to define a [custom Vega expression function](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/extensibility/) in javascript using either [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) or [Number.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

For example:

```
 vega.expressionFunction("formatLakh", (num) => new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {style: "currency", currency: "INR", maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(num));
```

or

```
vega.expressionFunction("formatLakh", (num) => Number(num).toLocaleString('en-IN', {style: "currency", currency: "INR", maximumFractionDigits: 2}));
```

In Vega, call this function within Vega expression, e.g.

```
{"signal": "'Category ' + formatLakh(12345678.9555)"}
```

and the (rounded) number will be displayed as: **₹1,23,45,678.96**